# Create radiobuttons on page from serverside in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a get method where i have a list of name.

```
Public ActionResult GetlistOfNames()
{
    listofPersons = SomeListOfGuys;
    // i want to display this as a radiobutton on the clientside
}
```

How can i do that?

The problem i am facing is when i try to do that i get text under the div like

```
<input id="name" type="radio" name="Personname"/>
```

and not the actual radiobuttons.

Please help me with the same.

Comment: Can you provide the bit of the view or JS that is representative of your HTML?  It seems to me that you maybe inserting html as text somewhere, what is being placed in your div is proper html, it's just not being rendered by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You would define this in the associated view for the action.  Within the view, you can use the Html helper method 'RadioButtonFor' method that will build the html for you given an appropriate list.  You can find more details on the specific method [on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: but i cannot use RadioButtonFor from serverside.
I want to get my radiobuttons from server side to clientside.

Comment: The razor view is still executed server side, the only piece that is sent to the client is the generated HTML.  I guess I'm not understanding your question accurately - could you clarify what you are trying to accomplish rather than do?

Answer (score 0):

I will make the assumption here that you are needed to render a dynamically generated list of radiobuttons, with 1 being selected by the user....

Your server side code (in the Controller Action method or, better yet, in the ViewModel props/methods) should return an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Each item in that list will have its Text and Value properties set by your code, in some kind of `foreach` from your actual data source.

I prefer to use 'fat' ViewModels, so all the work is done in the Model class, and NOT in the controller. You CAN just create that `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and throw it into the ViewBag like `ViewBag.NameChoices = GetSelectItemsFromDataWhatever();`, thats right in your controller.

In your View, you can bind a list of SelectItems to the equivalent of an ASP:RadioButtonList with the following extention method:

```
// jonlanceley.blogspot.com/2011/06/mvc3-radiobuttonlist-helper.html
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listOfValues)
{
    var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<span class='RadioButtonListFor'> ");

        if (listOfValues != null)
        {
            // Create a radio button for each item in the list
            foreach (SelectListItem item in listOfValues)
                {
                    // Generate an id to be given to the radio button field
                    var id = string.Format("{0}_{1}", metaData.PropertyName, item.Value);

                    // Create and populate a radio button using the existing html helpers

                    var htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    htmlAttributes.Add("id", id);

                    if (item.Selected)
                        htmlAttributes.Add("checked", "checked");

                    var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, item.Value, htmlAttributes);


                    // Create the html string that will be returned to the client
                    // e.g. <label<input data-val="true" data-val-required="You must select an option" id="TestRadio_1" name="TestRadio" type="radio" value="1" />Line1</label>
                    sb.AppendFormat("<label>{0} {1}</label> ", radio, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Text));
                }
        }

        sb.Append(" </span>");
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
}
```

And bind it in your View:

```
@Html.RadioButtonListFor(model => model.SelectedName, ViewBag.NameChoices)
```

Your Model will need a prop of 'SelectedName' for the above to work, which will be bound to the selected radio button on postback.